# Easiest way to convert "a/b/c" to ["a/b/c", "a/b", "a"]

Tags: ruby, regex

In Ruby, I'd like to convert a slash-separate String such as "foo/bar/baz" into ["foo/bar/baz", "foo/bar", "foo"]. I already have solutions a few lines long; I'm looking for an elegant one-liner. It also needs to work for arbitrary numbers of segments (0 and up).

Comment: You do know of `FileUtils.mkdir_p`, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The highest voted answer works, but here is a slightly shorter way to do it that I think will be more readable for those not familiar with all the features used there:

```
a=[]; s.scan(/\/|$/){a << $`}
```

The result is stored in `a`:

```
> s = 'abc/def/ghi'
> a=[]; s.scan(/\/|$/){a << $`}
> a
["abc", "abc/def", "abc/def/ghi"]
```

If the order is important, you can reverse the array or use `unshift` instead of `<<`.

Thanks to dkubb, and to the OP for the improvements to this answer.

Comment: On ruby 1.8.7 the result is only #=> "abc/def/ghi" and not the array as specified in the answer

Comment: @nas: The return value will be the string in any version of ruby. The requested array will be in the `a` variable. If you were aware of that and were just nitpicking, feel free to ignore my comment.

Comment: You could simplify the code in the block further by doing:

    a=[];
    'abc/def/ghi'.scan(/\/|$/){a<<$`}

Comment: I'm accepting this with the caveat that using unshift would eliminate the need for a reverse :)

Comment: @Yehuda Katz: Using unshift this will become O(n^2) instead of O(n) (I'm assuming that scan can go linearly through the string with the given regex), so using reverse should be much more efficient.

Answer (score 12):

```
"foo/bar/baz".enum_for(:scan, %r{/|$}).map {Regexp.last_match.pre_match}
```

Comment: Wow. That's almost lisp without all the parens.

Comment: good！more easier code "foo/bar/baz".enum_for(:scan, %r{/|$}).map {$`}

Answer (score 0):

Not quite as efficient as the chosen answer, and gives `[]` when given an empty string, rather than `[""]`, but its a real one liner :P

```
s.split('/').inject([]) { |a,d| a.unshift( [a.first,d].compact.join('/') ) }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
->(l,s,z){
    ( t = s[/#{z}.[^\/]*/] ) && [l[l,s,t], t]
}.tap{ |l|
    break l[l,'a/b/c','']
}.flatten.compact
```