# ruby regex: match and get position(s) of

Tags: ruby, regex

I'd like to match a regex and get the position in the string of the match

For example,

```
"AustinTexasDallasTexas".match_with_posn /(Texas)/
```

I'd like `match_with_posn` to return something like: `[6, 17]` where 6 and 17 are the start positions for both instances of the word Texas.

Is there anything like this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get indexes of all occurrences of a pattern in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4274388/how-to-get-indexes-of-all-occurrences-of-a-pattern-in-a-string)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Using Ruby 1.8.6+, you can do this:

```
require 'enumerator' #Only for 1.8.6, newer versions should not need this.

s = "AustinTexasDallasTexas"
positions = s.enum_for(:scan, /Texas/).map { Regexp.last_match.begin(0) }
```

This will create an array with:

```
=> [6, 17]
```

Comment: If you want to find atea in Isateateatest it will return [2], but 5 is also a possibility

Comment: The "a" in index 5 is used to match the "atea" found at index 2.  If you search for "ate", you will get an array of `[2, 5, 8]`. If you want to find overlapping matches, then use a lookahead assertion: `/(?=(atea))/`.  `positions = s.enum_for(:scan, /(?=(atea))/).map { Regexp.last_match.begin(0) } #=> [2, 5]`

Comment: Can the person who down voted this please explain the down vote?

Comment: Can you explain this in details.

Comment: It's returning an enumerator for `scan`, which finds the matches in a string for the argument passed to it, in this case, `/Texas/`. Without the enumerator, it would normally return the part of the string that matched. Since we are using the enumerator, we can map over the matches in such a way that we can return the index for each `scan` result. What essentially happens is that each step in the `map` call calls `next` on the enumerator returned by `enum_for` and then returns the value of what is inside the block.

Answer (score 31):

Sort of, see [`String#index`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/classes/String.html#M000757)

```
"AustinTexasDallasTexas".index /Texas/
=> 6
```

Now, you could extend the String API.

```
class String
  def indices e
    start, result = -1, []
    result << start while start = (self.index e, start + 1)
    result
  end
end
p "AustinTexasDallasTexas".indices /Texas/
=> [6, 17]
```

Comment: Suppose the string were `“aaaa”` and `e` were `”aa”`. The question is unclear as to whether the desired return value is `[0,1,2]` or `[0,2]`. You return the former. To return the latter make `index`’s second argument `start+e.size` and initialize `start` to `-e.size`. No need for `self.`.

Answer (score 4):

```
"AustinTexasDallasTexas".gsub(/Texas/).map { Regexp.last_match.begin(0) }
  #=> [6, 17]
```

or

```
"AustinTexasDallasTexas".gsub('Texas').map { Regexp.last_match.begin(0) }
  #=> [6, 17]
```

---

This uses the (underutilized) form of [String#gsub](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.3/String.html#method-i-gsub) that has a single argument, no block and returns an enumerator.

This form of `gsub` is seen to have *nothing* to do with replacing substrings in a string. Rather, it simply enumerates matches of its argument. Arguably, it should be a separate string method, possibly named `each_match`.

---

I have found many uses for this form of `gsub`. It's a bit off-topic, but considering the general lack of awareness of how it can be used to advantage, let me give another example of its use.

Suppose we are given a string

```
str = "aabccc"
```

and wish to return an array containing all substrings of consecutive characters that are equal (i.e., `["aa", "ccc"]`) .

We can do that by matching

```
rgx = /(.)\1+/
```

If we use [String#scan](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.3/String.html#method-i-scan) we obtain

```
str.scan(rgx)
  #=> [["a"], ["c"]]
```

This return value--which is not what we want--reflects the way `scan` works when its argument is a regular expression that contains a capture group.

By contrast, if we use `gsub` we obtain

```
enum = str.gsub(rgx)
  ##<Enumerator: "aabccc":gsub(/(.)\1+/)>
```

```
enum.to_a
  #=> ["aa", "ccc"]
```