# Get the index of all characters in ruby

Tags: ruby, string, character

I am trying to get the index of string which has duplicate characters. But if I have same characters it keeps returning the index of first occurrence of that character

```
    str = "sssaadd"

    str.each_char do |char|
       puts "index: #{str.index(char)}"
    end

Output:-
index: 0
index: 0
index: 0
index: 3
index: 3
index: 5
index: 5
```

Comment: Are you trying to always get all characters plus their index position as the end result? Or get something more general (i.e. a method that tells you position of the 5th 'z' in a string, or a method that if passed a string and a character, gives you all index positions of that character)? It may be worth showing an imagined function that returns what you want . . .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `Enumerator#with_index`:

```
str = "sssaadd"
str.each_char.with_index do |char, index|
  puts "#{index}: #{char}"
end
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to find all indices of duplicated substrings, you can use this:

```
'sssaadd'.enum_for(:scan, /(.)\1/).map do |match| 
  [Regexp.last_match.begin(0), match.first]  
end
# => [[0, "s"], [3, "a"], [5, "d"]]
```

Here we `scan` all the string by regex, that finds duplicated characters. The trick is that block form of `scan` doesn't return any result, so in order to make it return block result we convert `scan` to enumerator and add a `map` after that to get required results.

See also: [ruby regex: match and get position(s) of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5241653/ruby-regex-match-and-get-positions-of)

Answer (score 1):

You also use this

```
  str = "sssaadd"

  arr=str.split('')

  arr.each_with_index do|char,index|
     puts "index : #{index}"
  end
```