# Find all indices of a substring within a string

Tags: ruby

I want to be able to find the index of all occurrences of a substring in a larger string using Ruby. E.g.: all "in" in "Einstein"

```
str = "Einstein"
str.index("in") #returns only 1
str.scan("in")  #returns ["in","in"]
#desired output would be [1, 6]
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The standard hack is:

```
indices = "Einstein".enum_for(:scan, /(?=in)/).map do
  Regexp.last_match.offset(0).first
end
#=> [1, 6]
```

Comment: Nice one, tok. Note `"nnnn".enum_for(:scan, /nn/).map { Regexp.last_match.offset(0).first } #=> [0, 2]`. If `[0, 1, 2]` is the desired return value, change the regex (`/nn/`) to `/(?=nn)/`.

Comment: Good points, @Cary. I guess in most cases we'd want the second, updated.

Comment: imho, considering ruby, this should be part of language

Answer (score 9):

```
def indices_of_matches(str, target)
  sz = target.size
  (0..str.size-sz).select { |i| str[i,sz] == target }
end

indices_of_matches('Einstein', 'in')
  #=> [1, 6]
indices_of_matches('nnnn', 'nn')
  #=> [0, 1, 2]
```

The second example reflects an assumption I made about the treatment of overlapping strings. If overlapping strings are not to be considered (i.e., `[0, 2]` is the desired return value in the second example), this answer is obviously inappropriate.

Comment: Simple and clean, probably I'd go with this.

Comment: This is more correct answer to the question than https://stackoverflow.com/q/4274388/322020 because it uses string, not regex, as OP asked for.

Answer (score 6):

This is a more verbose solution which brings the advantage of not relying on a global value:

```
def indices(string, regex)
  position = 0
  Enumerator.new do |yielder|
    while match = regex.match(string, position)
      yielder << match.begin(0)
      position = match.end(0)
    end
  end
end

p indices("Einstein", /in/).to_a
# [1, 6]
```

It outputs an `Enumerator`, so you could also use it lazily or just take the `n` first indices.

Also, if you might need more information than just the indices, you could return an `Enumerator` of `MatchData` and extract the indices:

```
def matches(string, regex)
  position = 0
  Enumerator.new do |yielder|
    while match = regex.match(string, position)
      yielder << match
      position = match.end(0)
    end
  end
end

p matches("Einstein", /in/).map{ |match| match.begin(0) }
# [1, 6]
```

To get the behaviour described by @Cary, you could replace the last line in block by `position = match.begin(0) + 1`.

Answer (score 1):

#Recursive Function

```
    def indexes string, sub_string, start=0
      index = string[start..-1].index(sub_string)
      return [] unless index
      [index+start] + indexes(string,sub_string,index+start+1)
    end
```

#For better Usage I would open `String` class

```
  class String

    def indexes sub_string,start=0
      index = self[start..-1].index(sub_string)
      return [] unless index
      [index+start] + indexes(sub_string,index+start+1)
    end

  end
```

This way we can call in this way: `"Einstein".indexes("in") #=> [1, 6]`

Comment: This is fantastic because it's so much faster than the other options. Thankyou!