# How to replace the captured group in Ruby

Tags: regex, ruby

I would like to replace the captured group of a string with the elements of an array.

I am trying something like this:

```
part_number = 'R1L16SB#AA'
regex = (/\A(RM|R1)([A-Z])(\d\d+)([A-Z]+)#?([A-Z])([A-Z])\z/)
g = ["X","Y","Z"]
g.each do |i|
  ren_m,ch_conf,bit_conf,package_type,packing_val,envo_vals = part_number.match(regex).captures
  m = part_number.sub! packing_val,i
  puts m
end
```

My code with array `g = ["X","Y","Z"]` is giving desired output as:

```
R1L16SB#XA
R1L16SB#YA
R1L16SB#ZA
```

The captured group `packing_val` is replaced with

```
g = ["X","Y","Z"]
```

But when the array has elements which are already present in the string then it is not working:

```
g = ["A","B","C"]
```

outputs:

```
R1L16SB#AA
R1L16SB#BA
R1L16SC#BA
```

But my expected output is:

```
R1L16SB#AA
R1L16SB#BA
R1L16SB#CA
```

What is going wrong and what could be the possible solution?

Comment: I think it's better and easier to do it without regex. I updated the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sub!` will replace the first match every iteration on `part_number` which is outside of the loop.

What happens is:

In the first iteration, the first A will be replaced with A giving the same

```
R1L16SB#AA
        ^
```

In the second iteration, the first A will be replaced by B giving

```
R1L16SB#BA
        ^
```

In the third iteration, the first B will be replaced by C giving

```
R1L16SC#BA
      ^
```

One way to get the desired output is to put `part_number = 'R1L16SB#AA'` inside the loop.

[Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/6FnDYn)

Comment: @The fourth bird Thanks ! Is there a way where I don't need to capture the position all over again for new array elements,once I capture the position of 'packing_val'  it  can replaced with ["A","B","C"] directly ? as of now I am matching the string with regex and capturing the position for all the array elements.

Comment: @code_t The current answers are for the original question. Instead of modifying the question, you could always ask a new one. Perhaps [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5241653/ruby-regex-match-and-get-positions-of) or [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4274388/how-to-get-indexes-of-all-occurrences-of-a-pattern-in-a-string) can be helpful.

Comment: Thanks! I have removed the new query from this question

Answer (score 1):

You mutated your `part_number` every iteration. That's the reason.

Just switch to `sub` without bang:

```
m = part_number.sub(packing_val, i)
```

You can do it without regex:

```
part_number = 'R1L16SB#AA'

g = %w[X Y Z]

g.each do |i|
  pn = part_number.dup
  pn[-2] = i
  puts pn
end
```

Comment: Thanks !  Is there a way where I don't need to capture the position all over again for new array elements,once I capture the position of 'packing_val' it can replaced with ["A","B","C"] directly ? as of now I am matching the string with regex and capturing the position for all the array elements.